# Insert selected text file after existing text in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have created a macro in PowerPoint that does the following: User clicks text frame on the slide. It names the frame and opens a dialog for them to choose from a list of text documents. They choose one and the text is read and inserted into the named text frame.

Here's the insert part of the code:

```
Dim file As Object
Dim Text As String

Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(vrtSelectedItem, 1)
Text = file.ReadAll
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Text 'Insert the text into the text frame
```

The problem I have is that it clears any existing text in the frame, instead of adding to it. I really need to add the newly selected text after any existing content in the frame. For instance, if they are adding in a selection of quotes, they need to add one after the other.

Can anyone advise on ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & Text
```

Or:

```
oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & VbCRLF & Text
```